# PHP Mysql insert form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have tables called "Student" that has Student ID and Name attributes also, "Class" that has Class ID and Class Name and also "Student_in_Class" that has student ID and class ID as foreign keys. How can I do insertion form that will insert student name and from dropdown menu get classes that are inside class table and have it saved in Student_in_Class associative table?

Comment: So you're wondering, for instance, if you had a drop down menu with the list of students, and another drop down menu with the list of classes, how could you add the selected student, and selected class to the "Student_in_Class" table?

Comment: give your code or a design structure so that it can be easy to understand that what you wanna do.